# onload event listener is not invoked after awaiting on an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, onload

My code loads a JSON file that is later used in a function called `serverTest`.

So I have this code:

```
async function fetchJSON(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        headers: { accept: "application/json" }
    });
  
    return response.json();
}

const config = await fetchJSON("./config.json");

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    serverTest(0);
});

const serverList = new Map(Object.entries(config.servers));

function serverTest(index) {
    // code including serverList
}
```

The problem is that the load event handler does not run.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Doesn't the window load event fire before you are executing? It's not an even that fires for each fetch.

Comment: Uhm possible, but if I put it before the async function, it call the function too early because serverList isn't initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by delaying setting up the event handler until the JSON is loaded, you're missing the `load` event.

In the vast majority of use cases (but from the comments, not yours), just remove the event handler entirely:

```
async function fetchJSON (url) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        headers: { accept: "application/json" }
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.json();
}

const config = await fetchJSON("./config.json");
serverTest(0); // <==== Not wrapped in a `load` event handler

const serverList = new Map(Object.entries(config.servers));

function serverTest(index) {
    //Code including serverList
}
```

If you make sure your `script` tag uses `type="module"` (which yours must do, if you're using top-level `await` like that), it won't be run until the page HTML is fully loaded and the DOM has been built. (Unless you also have the `async` attribute on it; [details](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-async).)

In your use case, waiting for the `load` event genuinely does make sense, so you'll have to wait until both `load` *and* the `fetch` are done:

```
async function fetchJSON (url) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        headers: { accept: "application/json" }
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.json();
}

// Hook up the `load` event *before* loading `config.json`,
// get a promise for when it fires
const loadPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    window.addEventListener("load", resolve);
});
// Load and wait for `config.json`
const config = await fetchJSON("./config.json");
// Wait for the `load` event (waits only ***very*** briefly
// if the event has already fired, otherwise waits for it
// to fire)
await loadPromise();
serverTest(0);

const serverList = new Map(Object.entries(config.servers));

function serverTest(index) {
    //Code including serverList
}
```

---

Side note: Notice I added a check for `ok` before calling `json`. `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors. This is (IMHO) a footgun in the `fetch` API I cover on my old anemic blog [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: But I really need to wait for all pictures to be loaded (there is a lot of pictures that are loaded, just removed the code to make it more clear) before calling serverTest function

Comment: @DarePhoenix - Ah, okay, then `load` is the thing for that. :-) But I'm curious: Why do you have to wait for the pictures to be loaded to do `serverTest`?

Comment: Because the server test is actually connecting to a list of servers, and check for each the number of players, and the latency, and then the client will connect to the server with the lowest latency. The problem is that if I run serverTest while loading pictures, it give a false latency because there is a lot of downloaded things

Comment: @DarePhoenix - Nice one! Thanks for satisfying my curiosity. 99.9% of the time I see people using the `load` event, they're using it incorrectly. You're the 0.1%. :-D

Comment: ‘If you make sure your `script` tag uses `type="module"` (which yours must do, if you're using top-level `await` like that), it won't be run until the page HTML is fully loaded and the DOM has been built.’ — unless the `async` attribute is also present…